# Collocations for the word FACULTY

Tags: collocations

Which one is right, faculty of science Or faculty of sciences?
I think "sciences" is better as it refers to multiple departments.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(Faculty+of+Science)%2C(Faculty+of+Sciences)%2C(Faculty+of+Arts+and+Sciences)%2C(Faculty+of+Arts+and+Science)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Faculty%20of%20Science%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Faculty%20of%20Sciences%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Faculty%20of%20Arts%20and%20Sciences%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Faculty%20of%20Arts%20and%20Science%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: If you're talking about a specific school, call it whatever your school calls it.

Answer (score 1):

One form isn't necessary more correct than the other; you'll find some institutions that use one and other institutions that use the other, and many others that use both— or neither.

*Science* in the broad sense of the system of knowledge developed and organized through the scientific method is not countable, but like most non-count nouns in English, it can be used as a count noun. Individual branches of sciences are known as the *sciences*, much in the same way that a bakery can have a selection of *breads* in its selection of *bread*, and you discover many *truths* in the pursuit of *truth*.

If an institution perceived *science* as a particular branch of knowledge, it might well organize all science and related disciplines in a Faculty (or *School* or *Department* or *Division* or *College* etc.) of Science. You can find examples of them all around the world: the [National University of Singapore](http://www.science.nus.edu.sg/), the [University of Sydney](http://sydney.edu.au/science/), the [University of Regina](http://www.uregina.ca/science/), the [University of St. Andrews](https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/study/ug/options/faculties/science/), the [Massachusetts Institute of Technology](https://science.mit.edu/) and so on.

But other institutions might prefer to treat sciences as related but independent disciplines, taking a plural, and thus have a Faculty of Sciences, as do [Singapore Polytechnic](http://www.sp.edu.sg/wps/portal/vp-spws/schcls), [University of Adelaide](https://sciences.adelaide.edu.au/), the [University of Quebec at Montreal](http://www.international.uqam.ca/pages/science_en.aspx), the [University of York](https://www.york.ac.uk/about/departments/sciences/), or [North Carolina State University](https://sciences.ncsu.edu/).

Neither form is globally preferable, although there may be some regional patterns. Indeed, some institutions use both forms; the University of Auckland has, on the one hand, a [Faculty of Science](http://www.science.auckland.ac.nz/), but additionally, a [Faculty of Medical and Health Sciences](https://www.fmhs.auckland.ac.nz/).

The same point can be made for the use of *Faculty of Art* vs. *Faculty of the Arts* (although *arts* is a slippery term, as very often in education it refers to the *liberal arts*, not the *fine arts*).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "faculty of the sciences", like "faculty of the humanities".

Comment: Would you explain a bit more why you prefer it or offer some supporting evidence that it is more commonly used/better than the alternative? I don't disagree with you, but I don't think one person's preference is that helpful for a learner.